# Extract only 1 month from a multi-year netcdf file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, netcdf, cdo-climate

I am quite new to programming and I wanted to know if you could help me. I have a file that contains daily precipitation data from 2000 to 2020. I think with `pandas` I could create a dataframe that contains only the values ​​of the month of January but I can't understand how. Or maybe with `CDO` create a new file that only contains those values. Could someone help me? I would appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

The `cdo` solution would be

```
cdo selmon,n in.nc out.nc
```

where *n* is the number of the month, in your case n=1, so

```
cdo selmon,1 in.nc out.nc
```

You can also specify a list of months or a range using the forward slash, e.g.

```
cdo selmon,3/5 in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps -

1. Add a month column to your dataframe

`df['month']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month`

2. Select the rows you want using the condition df.month == 1

`df[(df['month'] == 1)]`

Comment: Whe i used that they say me "key error: Date"

Comment: import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

ds = xr.open_dataset('C:/Users/ferfo/Desktop/2020.nc')
df = ds.to_dataframe()
df= pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month

This is my code

Comment: and this is the dataframe: datetime lon lat crs precip

Comment: what is the name of the date column in your dataset - if header are not included , then you have to say ... df.columns = [list of columns] ... the column names should be in correct order conforming to the dataset, after that you should be able to use the date column as 'date' and use the code